# Multiple lines and columns in Specflow

Tags: c#, selenium, cucumber, specflow

I have a Specflow table that looks like this.

```
 When I Perform POST Operation for "/example/" with body
 | answerValue1  | answerValue2 | countryCode | Cash    |
 | Yes           | Yes          | AD          | 76-100% |  
 |               |              | AF          |         |
```

The column CountryCode is the only one that can be multiple choices.
 What I tried to do was to add the columns to dictionary with a simple tableExtenstions

```
 public class TableExtensions
        {
            public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(Table table)
            {
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var row in table.Rows)
                {
                    dictionary.Add(row[0], row[1]);
                }
                return dictionary;
            }
      }
```

and call it from the method.

```
var dictionary = TableExtensions.ToDictionary(table);
var countryCode = dictionary["countryCode"];
```

Unfortnally I get error ***The given key was not present in the dictionary***, 
since the dictionary only returns two values from the first and the second Key

Ofcourse if I change the keys to `row[2], row[3]` it gets the right columns. 
But I would like to reuse the Table Extension.

Also i tried to increment them, but it only took the first to columns

```
 var i = 0;
                foreach (var row in table.Rows)
                {
                    dictionary.Add(row[i], row[i]);
                    i++;
                }
```

Does anyone has a better solution?

Comment: Please check https://joebuschmann.com/working-effectively-with-specflow-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want the dictionary to ultimately contain, but as you mention that manually changing the rows it looks for to:

```
row[2], row[3]
```

gives the data you want, perhaps this would give you the reusability you're looking for:

```
 public class TableExtensions
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(Table table, int columnOne, int columnTwo)
        {
            int i = 0;

            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var row in table.Rows)
            {
                dictionary.Add(row[columnOne], row[columnTwo]);
            }
            return dictionary;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
var dictionary = TableExtensions.ToDictionary(table, 2, 3);
```

This produces a dictionary with the following contents:

[image: Dictionary contents]

You could get the country code like this:

```
foreach (var row in dictionary)
{
    var countryCode = row.Key;
    var score = row.Value ?? string.empty;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was out after. Thank you so much for the help! <3

Answer (score 1):

Given the simplicity of the country codes I would make them a comma separated list and use a vertical table instead:

```
When I Perform POST Operation for "/example/"
    | Field        | Value  |
    | answerValue1 | ...    |
    | answerValue2 | ...    |
    | countryCodes | AD, AF |
    | cash         | ...    |
```

In your step definition:

```
var example = table.CreateInstance<ExampleRow>();

// use example.GetCountryCodes();
```

And the ExampleRow class to parse the table into an object:

```
public class ExampleRow
{
    public string AnswerValue1 { get; set; }
    public string AnswerValue2 { get; set; }

    private string[] countryCodes;

    public string CountryCodes
    {
        get => string.Join(", ", countryCodes);
        set => countryCodes = value.Split(", ");
    }

    public string[] GetCountryCodes()
    {
        return countryCodes;
    }
}
```